# Placing many images on top of another image with CSS

Tags: html, css

Beginner in CSS here.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to place check marks or X-es on top of a country map and I am trying to find the best way to do this.(open to learn JS for this)

So far, I have placed my map in a div and centered it, with HTML code `<img src="check mark">` after the map image.

I will do this for every check mark i have to add, but is it there any better solution ?

```css
.container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="Map_image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an example of what i want to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXUHz.jpg

Comment: I made  you a snippet. Please use placeholder.com or similar or imgur to show us a [mcve]

Comment: `position: absolute;  top: 300px;  right: 500px;` for all images with class="check" will stack the images on top of eachother

Comment: And a better solution is using content in your css: http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/check%20mark

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the answer. Yes, i know that, i was thinking about making a class for every map zone that i want to check. This is my no-brainer solution, was wondering if there's another. i will edit my question with an example of what i want to achieve, as my code is being written on a different computer, with no internet connection, it will be just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is create a wrapper div with `position: relative` and place the map and the Xes inside it. Then make map fit with the wrapper (i.e. 100% width and height or whatever) then make all Xes `position: absolute` and position them accordingly using `top: left: right: bottom:` properties

Here's a working sample. Try to run it.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

img.map {
  width: 100%;
}

img.marker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
}

.marker.x1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}


.marker.x2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="map" src="https://www.onlygfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/world-map-vector.png" alt="map">
  
  <img class="marker x1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b1/7e/59/b17e59bc32383f7878c9132081f37c60.jpg" alt="x1">
  
  <img class="marker x2" src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b1/7e/59/b17e59bc32383f7878c9132081f37c60.jpg" alt="x1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! This is somewhat similar with what I was trying, just placing every mark with `top: right:` and creating a class for every mark. Was looking for a better solution if there is any, but if not, I will just use this. thank you, again!

Comment: @bogdaN , np. In terms of pure css, I can't think of any better way to place two images to on top of each other than position relative and absolute. But the cons of this approach is that the placement become inaccurate when the screensize changes. You can calculate the placement accurately using jquery I think.